# how to backpatch basic blocks in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing c compiler, and don't know how to implement `goto` statement in my one pass compiler with llvm, for example:

```
int main() {
  goto label;
label:
  return 0 
}
```

since the parser is one pass, when I analyzed `goto label;`, I cannot get the llvm::BasicBlock which represent `label` since it does not exist yet, so I if I create a `br` to implement this goto statement, the parameter of BasicBlock is unknown.

So how can I use llvm to backpatch a basic block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is keep a map from label names to basic blocks, and create entries whenever you see either a label, and it doesn't matter whether the first mention is use or definition.

Comment: you mean as long as I see a label, no matter it is a definition or declaration, I create a basic block and save it in the symbol table, then add instructions later?

Comment: Right. That's simple and doesn't hurt much. It creates a few spare blocks more than is needed (three blocks for `label1: label2: label3: ` even though two of them just fall through). You may find the same approach beneficial for if/then/else: create an `else` block when you see `if`, and after then, you treat a missing else clause as if were `else {}`.

Comment: wow, I should really change my thinking mode, I always thought that basic blocks should only be created when I see a block, and add instructions immediately after it is created.